# Python Plotly Dash : responsive/ autosize indicator text

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, dash-bootstrap-components

How to resize text and numbers in indicator automatically when changed browser window size.

For example:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go 
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

indicator_style ={"height": 100, 'border-radius': '13px',
                                                       'background': '#FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box',
                                                       'border': '1px solid  #CECECE',
                                                       'box-shadow': '3px 3px 6px #00000029', 'padding': '6px',
                                                       }

fig_1 = go.Figure(go.Indicator(mode="number",
                                         title='<b>'+'Indicator 1'+'<b>',
                                         value=477526,
                                         number={'valueformat': '$,.0f'},
                                         domain={'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]}))
fig_1.update_traces(number_font_size=33, title_font_size=16, title_font_family='Roboto',
                                          title_font_color="#211C51")

fig_2 = go.Figure(go.Indicator(mode="number",
                                                     title='<b>'+'Indicator 2'+'<b>',
                                                     value=477526,
                                                     number={'valueformat': '$,.0f'},
                                                     domain={'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]}))
fig_2.update_traces(number_font_size=33, title_font_size=16, title_font_family='Roboto',
                                                title_font_color="#211C51")


fig_3 = go.Figure(go.Indicator(mode="number",
                                                     title='<b>'+'Indicator 3'+'<b>',
                                                     value=477526,
                                                     number={'valueformat': '$,.0f'},
                                                     domain={'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]}))
fig_3.update_traces(number_font_size=33, title_font_size=16, title_font_family='Roboto',
                                              title_font_color="#211C51")

fig_4 = go.Figure(go.Indicator(mode="number",
                                                     title='<b>'+'Indicator 4'+'<b>',
                                                     value=477526,
                                                     number={'valueformat': '$,.0f'},
                                                     domain={'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]}))
fig_4.update_traces(number_font_size=33, title_font_size=16, title_font_family='Roboto',
                                          title_font_color="#211C51")

fig_5 = go.Figure(go.Indicator(mode="number",
                                                       title='<b>'+'Indicator 5'+'<b>',
                                                       value=477526,
                                                       number={'valueformat': '$,.0f'},
                                                       domain={'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]}))
fig_5.update_traces(number_font_size=33, title_font_size=16, title_font_family='Roboto',
                                            title_font_color="#211C51")
fig_6 = go.Figure(go.Indicator(mode="number",
                                                      title='<b>'+'Indicator 6'+'<b>',
                                                      value=0.25,
                                                      number={'valueformat': '.2%'},
                                                      domain={'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]}))
fig_6.update_traces(number_font_size=33, title_font_size=16, title_font_family='Roboto',
                                           title_font_color="#211C51")

app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.SANDSTONE])
app.layout = html.Div([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([dcc.Graph(figure=fig_1, style=indicator_style)],width=2),
        dbc.Col([dcc.Graph(figure=fig_2, style=indicator_style)],width=2),
        dbc.Col([dcc.Graph(figure=fig_3, style=indicator_style)],width=2),
        dbc.Col([dcc.Graph(figure=fig_4, style=indicator_style)],width=2),
        dbc.Col([dcc.Graph(figure=fig_5, style=indicator_style)],width=2),
        dbc.Col([dcc.Graph(figure=fig_6, style=indicator_style)],width=2)
    ])

])

app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)  # Turn off reloader if inside Jupyter
```

Normal  and Small browser size:
[image: ![image|690x279](upload://43kIuhImPI91C5m8FSgYU1B2B58.jpeg)]

The indicator window decreases, but the text and numbers remain unchanged so nothing can be seen.

How can numbers and text be scaled down based on browser size?
Is there a way to detect the size of a browser window and place it as a condition within the text size settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I did understand correctly what's the problem you're facing but anyway I think you're not doing this in the best way.

To make the app responsive you need to add this metadata when you create the instance of your dash app:

```
app = dash.Dash(
    external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.SANDSTONE],
    meta_tags=[
        {
            "name": "viewport",
            "content": "width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1",
        }
    ],
)
```

Instead of using Plotly figures to it, try to implement this by using html.Div() with callbacks... So you can dynamically feed your app;

I will give you a simple example using your first indicator:

```
app.layout = html.Div(
[
    dbc.Row(
        [
            dbc.Col(
                html.Div(
                    [
                        html.Div(f"Indicator {n}", style={"textAlign": "center"}),
                        html.Div(
                            id=f"value-{n}",
                            children=f"R$ {477526:,}",
                            style={"textAlign": "center", "fontSize": "28px"},
                        ),
                    ],
                    style=indicator_style,
                )
            )
            for n in range(6)
        ],
    ),
]
```

)

By using the id in the html.Div you will be able to use a callback to send the data needed to your div and show as you want

Comment: Another problem I found is that you're hard-coding the style in some parts, which makes it break sometimes; Try to understand how CSS works and it will help you a lot